# More accurate estimation of mathematical constant $e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, parameter-estimation

Very often in books and also on Wikipedia we can find that:
$$e \approx \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
but I want more accurate estimation, it means instead using $\approx$ I wonder if I can use $\leq$, $\geq$ or $>,<$ and if it is possible how can I show that?

Comment: It should be either $(1\mathbf{+}1/n)^n$ or $1/e$.

Comment: @Peter Yes, Of course, sorry, my rush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following inequality holds:
$$(1+1/n)^n < e < (1+1/n)^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you have maybe any source when I can read about that inequality or see the proof of it?

Comment: @Mandlbrot: Pretty much any introductory book on calculus or mathematical analysis should have it. I don't have access to any textbooks right now.

Answer (score 3):

The following inequalities hold : 
$$\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n\lt e\lt\frac{2n+1}{2n}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n,$$
$$\frac{2n}{2n+1}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n+1}\lt e\lt\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n+1}.$$

Also, 
$$e\lt\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n+(1/2)}\lt e\times\exp\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}.$$

Comment: Very good bounds!

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I forgot the name of these inequalities...

Answer (score 1):

The approximation comes from the fact, that

$$lim_{n->\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$$

Comment: I know that it comes from this fact, but I don't know if I can made it more accurate or not

Comment: Since $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is increasing, it is lower than e for any n, as yury already said.

Comment: For calculating e, the taylor expansion $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! +\ ...$$ is much better as it converges much more quickly.

Comment: Can I also estimate the value $(1-\frac{1}{n})^x \approx e^{\frac{x}{n}}$ in the similiar way?

Comment: Do you mean the + - sign again ?

Comment: No, now I mean '-' (minus sign) :) Or maybe I should post it as new question?

Comment: Oh, I wanted to write on the right side $e^{\frac{-x}{n}}$

Comment: Probably yes, but since $e^x$ can be calculated fast and easy, I wonder why such estimates are necessary.

Comment: I just need this one to my estimations